# Ruby script to count access and complete downloads of the file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am open for the suggestions on the following:

- have a file on S3
- this file will be randomly downloaded by random people
- the volume of downloads is low, maybe 200-300 at most per day, on a spike, but usually might be as low as 5-10.
- file size is ~10-20mb.

I need somehow to count a) how many accesses to the file happened b) how many full (completed) downloads happened.

I believe the only good day is just have some Ruby or Node.js script. It'll count accesses, then somehow supply the file, and on final byte do the completed count.
Unfortunately, doesn't seem like a too nice of the approach.

Any better ideas?
I was also thinking about enabling access logging on S3 and then parsing logs, but that doesn't seem too good neither, as requires downloading and parsing logs.

Comment: What's so scary about downloading and parsing logs? Besides you can't guarantee people won't share the s3 link, resulting in downloads your app won't see

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with your first idea. Having some sort of server-side logic handling the counting stuff.

I don't know which type of clients are accessing your system, but with this approach you can parse additional data coming from your clients, like HTTP headers (if applicable), etc, and that can help you identifying the profile of your clients. That might not be useful at all to you, though.

Also, if you ever need to add more complicated logic (authentication, privileges, permissions, uploading files, etc), it will be much easier once you already have a backend application/script in place.